# postgresql and django - No unique identifier for this row

Tags: database, django, postgresql, phppgadmin

Two entries on my Django postgresql database are causing me a world of trouble when I go a-querying to create reports. When I try to delete these entries (via phpPgAdmin), I get the error "No unique identifier for this row." There are no duplicate IDs. I've tried updating all the fields. I've tried getting rid of these using the delete button and manual SQL commands. I'm out of ideas. Anyone know hot to give a row a unique identifier so I can get rid of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look up the row by the special ctid system column and then delete by that value.  ctid's are unique.

Answer (score 0):

The rows you are going to delete may be referenced in another table.
remove them or refer them to something else and, then try to remove your given rows.