# delete a row that is created by django using PHPPgAdmin?

Tags: django, postgresql, delete-row, phppgadmin

Using django, I added a new entry to my table. Now I want to delete it using `PHPPgAdmin (postgresql)`, but I get `No unique Identifier for this row` error. What is the problem?

django automatically adds an auto-incrementing primary key, so I cannot figure out what the issue is?

I read [this post,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650571/postgresql-and-django-no-unique-identifier-for-this-row) but it did not help. If you notice the image carefully, you will see that the primary  key column label is `id` but not `pk` as it should be in django.

[image]

EDIT: No primary key is seen on table;
[image]

But this is what django executes;

`python manage.py sql auth`

```
CREATE TABLE "auth_user" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "last_login" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "is_superuser" boolean NOT NULL,
    "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    "is_staff" boolean NOT NULL,
    "is_active" boolean NOT NULL,
    "date_joined" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)
;
```

EDIT: A screenshot from PHPPgAdmin, showing `id` as primary key
[image]

Comment: I assume by the screenshot that you mean PHPPgAdmin. If you use `psql` to run `\d thetablename` what's the output? Does it show a `PRIMARY KEY` ?

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` is listed after the table columns; check there.

Comment: I see the `PRIMARY KEY` as `id`

Comment: Screenshot not updated to reflect that, but if that's the case, sounds like the problem must be PHPPgAdmin. I've never used it myself, I just use `psql`, so I'm not sure what to advise from here.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I have updated with screenshot.

Comment: Is the "no unique identifier for this row" a Django error, or from PhpPgAdmin?

Comment: In django `pk` is an alias that always points to the primary key, irrespective if its called `id` or anything else; which is why it is recommended to be used.  What is the exact query you are running?

Comment: @CraigRinger: the error comes in pgAdmin3. The very first snapshot above.

Comment: @eagertoLearn That doesn't look like PgAdmin-III's UI to me, it looks like something from a web browser.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: when I try to delete a row, from pgAdmin3, it is not allowing me to delete. the snapshots show them.

Comment: @CraigRinger: sorry, I meant phpPGAdmin

Comment: Can you delete the row from psql? If so, this might be a bug in phppgadmin (and please do not confuse it with the actual [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug with phpPgAdmin.

I experienced a similar problem and went directly into psql (using the command `./manage.py dbshell`).

I tried deleting the row in question, and received a more helpful error message than the one from phpPgAdmin.  (In my case, that the row was being referenced by another table.)

I deleted the row referenced by the other table, and was then able to delete the row in question.